# How can I add a menu item to exit raspbian and get back to the CLI

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

When I boot up, I go directly into RetroPie. I can exit RetroPie and get back to the CLI to start Raspbian (`startx`). I learned that I can exit Raspbian with `pkill x` so I can start RetroPie back up, but is there a way to add an item to the rPi menu that does that?

Note, neither ctrl-alt-F1 or ctrl-alt-backspace work for me, probably because I’m using an old Mac keyboard.

Comment: Raspbian already has a menu to do that

Comment: Uh, really? Are you sure? There’s a way to stop raspbian and get back to the system prompt? I’ve tried all the menu items available. None of them have kicked me out to the system prompt. Is it available in a specific version of raspbian?

Comment: Which menu option is it?

Comment: I rarely use the GUI - I think it is a sub-menu of the Shut Down (or similar) called something like "Exit to the Command Line" NOTE this is not stopping Raspbian, just exiting the Desktop.

Comment: Yeah. I’ve tried all the shut down menu options. Nothing there exits to the command line. So, is there a way to add that option?

Comment: Are you running Raspbian - if so which version? This is a standard feature in Stretch, not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: I’m not actually sure. How can I tell which GUI desktop I’ve got? I believe it’s raspbian. I hadn’t heard the name raspbian until I set the pi up for the first time a month or so ago. I don’t usually run the desktop either, but I do occasionally. I usually just restart it to get into RetroPie, but now I have a server running, so I’d rather not have to restart anymore if I don’t have to.

Comment: Hi the exit to command line option only appears in the shutdown menu if your pi is set to boot into the command line first, if it's booting direct to the gui I don't think it appears. Although that said if you booting retropie, and then exiting retropie and starting the raspian desktop I would have thought it would be there, as the desktop hasn't been loaded. But maybe whatever script/program adds the menu option in just looks for a gui not just the raspian one.

Comment: Interesting. Regardless of how the desktop is started, I would have guessed that the ability to exit to the system prompt would be a popular use-case. I wonder why it wasn’t added in every case... So is there a setting somewhere where I can just always have that option? BTW, somehow, (until I edited it yesterday), both RetroPie *and* Raspbian have been starting at boot. RetroPie starts up first, then Raspbian takes over, then after about 20-30 seconds, it kicks out to the system prompt and asks me to login. I’m not sure how this happened, but I hope it will just go into RetroPie here on out.

Comment: Not sure about making it a permanent option to be honest. I think (and I'm only guessing here) that's it's for ease of use. So if someone has a pi but isn't nessecarily comfortable with the cli and only boots to the gui they never see the option whereas if you are comfortable and are booting to the cli then you get the option.  It does appear to replace the log out option in the menu so instead of shut down reboot and log out you have return to cli. There is likely to be other ways of doing it but I've never really looked into it myself I tend to use all my pi's via ssh.